# How to start angular4 project?

Tags: angular

I am previously working with the angular2 project, now i have a requirement to create a angular4 project. My question is

1. From where do i get the angular4 project?
2. Should i have to do anything different to get a angular4 project? if not then how will i identify that it is an angular 4 project?
3. should i have to use @angular/cli for angular 4 project?
4. is there any different setup like package.json for angular4?

One of my collegue said that using cli commands itself means we are using angular4, is that true?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as "Angular 2" or "Angular 4", by the naming convention it's just **Angular**.

What you are looking for is the version number of the angular packages. (Angular uses semantic versioning to reflect changes into the version number, see [semver](http://semver.org/)).

For a new Angular project you could just use the latest `@angular/cli`, it automatically installs the latest version of Angular which is compatible to the CLI version and sets up all the requirements for the build/bundling process. (**recommended for beginners**)*

If you don't want to use the CLI, you can look out for angular starter repositories/seeds or create your own project from scratch.

If you want to create your own project from scratch look for a tutorial how to setup Webpack with Angular (version ^4.0.0).

If you already have an Angular project which is using version ~2.x.x, you can just update your dependencies and migrate your code. Or if you used the CLI before, follow the migration guide [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli).

** you can later eject the webpack config to do more complex stuff in the build process on your own*

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular CLI yes, another very comprehensive seed is [mgechev](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is through CLI (Command line interface). It is easy and it also take care of all the imports and server required in angular project.
You must install nodeJS first of all to make it work.

```
1. Download nodejs
2. Open command prompt and type npm install -g @angular/cli ----> This will install Angular CLI into the system which will help us to install the angular application.
If you face any issue in installing it like checksum update the npm and 
clear npm cache

                        npm install -g npm
                        npm cache clean --force

1. Once cli is installed, create a folder where you want to create the project from scratch
2. ng new <<application name>>
3. Open the project in an editor
4. From command prompt, start the angular server by :: ng serve
5. open your browser on http://localhost:4200/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the link [Here](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/55/How-to-Install-an-Angular-4-App#) . There are a number of ways you can get angular 4. I'd recommend manual approach because if you use CLI you get the angular version depending upon the version of CLI. For example, if you have angular CLI version 1.6.0 then you always get angular 5.

You can check your package.json file to know which angular version you've installed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, angular 2 & 4 doesn't really have big differences syntatically.

Angular 4 is just an imrovement over previous one like adding if then else, as in for loop, addition of titlecase in pipe filters, typescript version upgrade which is faster etc.
For further reference
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular4/angular4_overview.htm

Well google best suggest to use angular cli to work on angular & its used as same in prevoius versions  but there are other ways also to work on it apart from cli.

Answer (score -1):

There are only two different version. So you can use AngularJS (which is Angular  1.x) or Angular (which is Angular 2/4). Based on the usage you should update you versions of Node and npm to newest and that way you'll be using angular4. The creation of projects is still the same.

And for creating a project with ng new you have to download the angular-cli. That is done with the following command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Then with ng new you can create a new project:

```
ng new application-name
```

Comment: This does not create a project

Comment: Downvoted cause you dont explain that ng is part of the @angular/cli, and this wont work "out of the box" withouth installing the mentioned binaries

Comment: I've edited and explained more in detail. Thank you for your review.